# How to override a virtual function of an Abstract class calling another abstract class

Tags: c++, class, abstract, virtual-functions

I have a question about abstract classes and pure virtual functions, when I tried to use an abstract class I found that the pure virtual function return an instance of another abstract class, the code is like that:

```
 class A{
    virtual B *newB()=0;    
    }
```

The class B is too abstract :

```
class B{
virtual void function1()=0;
virtual void function2()=0;    
}
```

Then i have my header file C.hpp where im calling for class A :

```
class C: A{
virtual B *newB();    
}
```

In my C.cpp file i put my code :

```
#include "C.hpp"
 B *C::newB(){
return new B;
}
```

It can't return an instance of B because is too abstract. so how can I proceed to resolve this problem, I suggest to create another class that inherits from B and override function1 and function2, after that I can call this new D () instead of new B () what do you think about this solution thanks for any response.

Comment: Without a concrete class deriving from each abstract class, you can't do anything - what did you expect?

Answer (score 3):

Why would you get a member function `newD`? You can simply use:

```
B* C::newB() {
  return new D; // D* converts to B*, if B is a public base class of D
}
```

You might want to recall what virtual functions and abstract classes are for. They provide interfaces to hide implementation differences. The caller of `C::newB` only cares about one thing: an object that I can use like a `B`. The class `C` decides which implementation of the interface the caller gets. This is usually called a `Factory Pattern`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the "return" that is the problem, it is the "new B".  You cannot 'new' an abstract class.  You must instantiate a concrete class that derives from B.  You can happily return that as a pointer to B then.